# Заменить буквы в строке вариативными значениями python

Tags: python

Есть строка из 4 букв ABCX
Необходимо создать массив в котором будут строки, в которых X заменен сначала на A, потом B, C и D
Пробовал через replace, но он требует строку для замены
 `print([i for i in st i.replace("X","ABCD")])`
Ввод: ABCX
Вывод: ABCA, ABCB, ABCC, ABCD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не понял - вам вот это нужно?

```
text = "TEST XXX BEST"

res = [text.replace("X", letter) for letter in "ABCD"]

print(res)
```

Comment: Нууу не совсем
ABCX ->ABCA, ABCB, ABCC, ABCD
X может быть в любом месте

Comment: тогда я совсем не понял что нужно сделать - вы могли бы привести у себя в вопросе какой-то пример ответа или более точно описать что именно нужно сделать

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Comment: и чем тогда не подходит мой код? пишите `text = "ABCX"` и получаете последовательность из вашего вопроса

Answer (score 4):

```py
from itertools import product

text = 'TEST XXX BEST'  # Входные данные

placeholder = 'X'  # Что будем заменять
alph = 'ABC'  # алфавит букв, которыми будем заменять

template_str = text.replace(placeholder , '{}')  # Меняем места для замены на {}, чтобы затем к этой строке можно было применить format

result = [
    template_str.format(*seq)  # Подставляем комбинацию в строку
    for seq in product(alph, repeat=template_str.count('{}'))  # Для всех возможных комбинаций
]
```

---

В результате будет

```py
['TEST AAA BEST',
 'TEST AAB BEST',
 'TEST AAC BEST',
 'TEST ABA BEST',
 'TEST ABB BEST',
 'TEST ABC BEST',
 'TEST ACA BEST',
 'TEST ACB BEST',
 'TEST ACC BEST',
 'TEST BAA BEST',
 'TEST BAB BEST',
 'TEST BAC BEST',
 'TEST BBA BEST',
 'TEST BBB BEST',
 'TEST BBC BEST',
 'TEST BCA BEST',
 'TEST BCB BEST',
 'TEST BCC BEST',
 'TEST CAA BEST',
 'TEST CAB BEST',
 'TEST CAC BEST',
 'TEST CBA BEST',
 'TEST CBB BEST',
 'TEST CBC BEST',
 'TEST CCA BEST',
 'TEST CCB BEST',
 'TEST CCC BEST']
```

Comment: Оу, вау это даже больше чем то, что я просил

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools


def solve(text, char='X', replace='ABCD'):
    return map(''.join, itertools.product(*(x if x != char else replace for x in text)))


for line in solve('TEST XXX BEST'):
    print(line)
```

```
TEST AAA BEST
TEST AAB BEST
TEST AAC BEST
...
```

Comment: Потрясающее построение генератора для `product`!

Comment: @МихаилМуругов благодарю. просто увидел задание, и подумал, что на Haskell получилось бы красивое [решение](https://ideone.com/12GJiF). Ну а потом решил адаптировать для Python. На первый взгляд не очень похоже, но по смыслу близко.

Comment: Красивое, элегантное решение! Явно не для начинающих питонистов)

Comment: @MaxU да, скорее для конченых функциональщиков, которым везде монада списка мерещится :)